# hover CSS3 forced by other element

Tags: css, navigation, hover

Hey I wanna do a pure CSS3 dropdown navigation. If you hover the first item it changes the background and opens the dropdown child element. This is okay. But if I hover the dropdown element the changed background resets like its not hovered.

How can I change the style of an element forced by the hover of an other element?

Comment: Post your code so we can see, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Hover over "demos" in this example, this what you need? http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_drop.html

Comment: You need to close the first elements tag after the dropdowns element, something like http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stick to pure CSS3 you could put both objects into a container and define the color in this container. Overwrite it in the dropdown child if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[here's a quick CSS only dropdown](http://jsfiddle.net/sGUtQ/). the trick to preserve the background is to set the hover style to the main menu item, and not to the submenu item. events like hover, like JS, bubble up. hovering a child will also mean hovering the parent.